# How to resize an image through the terminal?

Tags: image-processing, command-line, resize, ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I have converted image through terminal using the following command:

```
convert myfigure.png myfigure.jpg
```

But I want to resize the height and width of the converted image. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try `convert input.png -resize 800x600 output.jpg` and see https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php for more options.

Comment: Yes it is working. I also saw another option in the documentation,

`convert -resize 50% input.png output.jpg`
Thanks @MarkSetchell
Can I do the same for multiple files using imagemagick ?

Comment: Yes `mogrify -resize 50% *.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the imutils python package.

```
import imutils

frameData = vs.read()
frameData = imutils.resize(frameData, width=600)
```

This should help.